# have 2 containers and 2 inkwell in a SingleChildScrollView. when user clicks on inkwell the screen should scroll to respective container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

i have a SingleChildScrollView in a column. having 2 inkwells in a row. below the row, i have 2 containers with different height and content. i want the screen to scroll to first container when user clicks on the first inkwell and screen should scroll to the second container when user clicks on the second inkwell.
the code is here:

```
class ExperienceCustomDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  ExperienceCustomDrawer({
    super.key,
  });


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Drawer(
        shape:const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(20),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
        ),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
        child:Container(
          color: Constants.black,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15, 30, 15),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      InkWell(
                          onTap:(){
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: const Icon(Icons.close, color: Constants.orange,))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 15, 30, 15),
                  child: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                    child: Text("Sea Food Experience",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Constants.white,
                        fontSize: 28,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                //THIS IS MY INKWELL ROW
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *0.6,
                  height: 70,
                  color: Constants.grey,
                  child:
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 30),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Flexible(
                                child: Text("Details",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Constants.orange,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                  ),
                                )),
                            Flexible(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 3,
                                  backgroundColor: Constants.orange,
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Flexible(
                                child: Text("Menus",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Constants.orange,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                  ),
                                )),
                            Flexible(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 3,
                                  backgroundColor: Constants.orange,
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),


                    ],
                  ),
                ),

//THIS IS THE FIRST CONTAINER
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                
                
                //THIS IS THE second CONTAINER
                Container(child: MenuCard()),



              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

i also want when user scroll the screen and the screen reaches to the second container the second inkwell should change its color to red showing that screen is on second container. if the user is on first container the first inkwell color should be red and the 2nd inkwell color should be orange.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches you could use.

1. use of scrollable with key
2. use of controllers in the list view
3. use of [scrollable_positioned_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list) Package

For more detail, you could refer to **[THIS](https://medium.com/@aakashpp/how-to-scroll-to-a-specific-widget-flutter-91c2ae711d32)**.